# Changing Sprite texture upon button touch

Tags: swift, textures

I am trying to change my Sprites texture upon touching a button on the same scene. The code I have been attempting to use has been fairly straightforward and basic.

```
Class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Hero")}

if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.button3 {
hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Hero2")

self.button3value++
} if (button3value % 2 == 0){
hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Hero")}
```

Obviously there is other code that actually involves the physics and qualities of the sprite but I figured this is the most relevant code.

What happens when this code is utilized is very strange and I can't figure out exactly what is going on. When "button3" is pressed, the sprite doesn't change textures and loses only some of its physics. It is still on the screen but doesn't rotate, doesn't engage in the jump function upon clicking the background, but still retains its collision detection.

Now, if I add in

```
 Class PlayScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
var hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Hero")}

if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.button3 {
hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Hero2")
addChild(hero)
self.button3value++
} if (button3value % 2 == 0){
hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Hero")}
```

Then, what seems to be a new sprite appears with all the characteristics and properties of the old sprite, with the proper image as well (this is what I want, same characteristics of the old sprite but a new image). But, the old inert sprite is still on the screen.

I can't quite figure out why SpriteKit is acting like this. Why are some physical properties remaining while some become inert after button is clicked? Why when I do addChild() for the same declared sprite, does it just appear behind the old sprite that has been rewritten? Is there any way I can keep the new sprite and just remove the old inert one that stays on the screen?

I really just want to replace the image and can't figure our why it's not working like that. I have several other buttons that work just fine changing variables in the same way I have written my code, but for some reason the textures and images are acting up.

Thank you.

Comment: If you only want to change a texture of a hero, then just change its texture. There is a texture property on SKSpriteNode... About physics, I guess that you are loosing physics because when you recreate a node, its just a SKSpriteNode...No physics body defined yet in that case...